# filter in vba to deselect item

Tags: excel, vba

I have 10 items in my filter list and I want to deselect one item based on cell A59 which can change from time to time so my data only consist of data from the remaining 9 category. I recorded my macro but I have no idea how to change the filter requirement based on cell A59.

The idea is I want to change cell A59 to e.g. "Mining" then run my macro and the sheet will auto filter "Mining" out from my results.

How do I incorporate that into my macro? Please help!

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$W$5002").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "Metal Fabricate/Hardware", "Mining", "Miscellaneous Manufactur", "Multi-National" _
    , "Office/Business Equip", "Oil&Gas", "Oil&Gas Services", "Packaging&Containers", _
    "Pharmaceuticals"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Are you just trying to select **everything** other than (for instance) "Mining", i.e you want the `Criteria1:="<>Mining"` (or, more specifically, `Criteria1:="<>" & Range("A59").Value`)?  Or do you want to exclude "Mining" and anything not in the array you're currently using (e.g. "Mining" and "Technology")?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! I am trying to select everything other than "Mining" or any other catergory based on the cell A59. so Criteria1:="<>" & Range("A59").Value works for me. But I want it to not only be restricted to just one category. So the macro should allow maybe select everything other than "Range("A59").Value" or "Range("A59").Value" and ""Range("A60").Value". How should I modify it?

Comment: You can have two Criteria on the filter, but if you need more than that you will need to select the ones you **do** want rather than the ones you **don't** want.  (To see how to do it with two exclusions, use the macro recorder while performing a filter using Text Filters / Does Not Equal and specifying two criteria, and then look at the code produced.)

Comment: Does it mean if I have 70 criteria on the filter and I want to deselect 5, I need to select 65 in the macro? Criteria1:=" " to Criteria65:=" " each referring to one cell?

Comment: You can only have two Criteria (`Criteria1` and `Criteria2`), but if you want to select 65 values you can use something like `Criteria1:=Array("Metal Fabricate/Hardware", "Mining", "Miscellaneous Manufactur", "Multi-National", "Office/Business Equip", "Oil&Gas", "Oil&Gas Services", "Packaging&Containers", "Pharmaceuticals"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`  (And, of course, `Array("Metal Fabricate/Hardware", "Mining", "Miscellaneous Manufactur", "Multi-National", "Office/Business Equip", "Oil&Gas", "Oil&Gas Services", "Packaging&Containers", "Pharmaceuticals")` could be replaced by a variable.)